# How to display search results onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, full-text-search, toggle

I have a search box that as the user types letters into the search box, we will filter and display the results. However, as the user types each letter the search results are getting toggled between showing and hiding.  I am very new to JS so I hope it could be an easy fix.

Here is my HTML:

```
See Below
```

Here is my toggle JS:

```
See Below
```

How can I tweak the JS to not toggle back and forth?

//Here are my edits to help answer the question.  This is the JS and HTML I am using to display the results:

HTML:

```
<div class="friendssearch" onclick="toggle_visibility('friendslist');">
  <div class="friendssearch">
    <div id="friendssearchbox"></div>
  </div>
        <ul id="friendslist" style="display: none;">
            <li>
              <a href="#">  
                <div class="friendsflybox" title="Friends Name">
                    <p class="friendsflyboxname">Ryan Bennett</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script> 
(function ($) {
 // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
 jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
   return (a.textContent || a.innerText || 
"").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
 };

 function listFilter(header, list) { // header is any element, list is an unordered list
 // create and add the filter form to the header
 var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
    input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput clearFieldBlurred  
ClearField","type":"text", "value":"Start typing a Name"});
$(form).append(input).appendTo(header);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.clearField').clearField();
}); 

$(input)
  .change( function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if(filter) {
      // this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
      // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
      $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
      $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
    } else {
      $(list).find("li").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  })
.keyup( function () {
    // fire the above change event after every letter
    $(this).change();
});
} 
//ondomready
$(function () {
  listFilter($("#friendssearchbox"), $("#friendslist"));
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013760/how-to-display-div-on-keyup-in-input
This may be help you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something similar to the code I have posted below. This assumes that you can access the object that contains the search results.

```
function toggle_visibility(id)
{
    //Check if there are any search results to display
    var searchResultLength = document.getElementById(searchResultID).innerHTML.length;

    if (searchResultLength > 0) // display div
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else //No search results, hide div
    {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to determine if you have search results to display ***before*** you attempt to toggle the div's visibility.

//EDIT AFTER COMMENTS

OK, so it looks like the results are adding li's to the ul. So, assuming that the code is taking away the li's as well as adding them, you should be checking for the number of elements in the ul == 0. See below.

```
$('#friendslist > li').length
```

To be honest, I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to determine exaclty what the code is 
doing. I'm certainly not a jquery expert. I would say if the above code doesn't get you going in the right direction, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No, I still can't seem to get it to work.  The ID is not picking up the amount of results.  Onclick, it is just displaying all the results without ever allowing to hide.

Comment: @RyanBennett, OK. I think we may need a little more information to helpy you out then. Where are the results being stored on the client? I assume that they are being returned via Ajax? If so, can you post the Ajax response handler?

Comment: I have them hard-coded in right now because I don't know how to code AJAX.  I am trying to do the same exact interaction that Facebook does with their left side search right above your online friends box.  I can get it working and searching but just can't get it to disappear if nothing is typed.  Does that help?

Comment: @RyanBennett, not a lot :). I need to see the object/element that the search results are stored in so I can show you how to check if they're empty (so we can hide the div). Don't be afraid to post up some code!

Comment: @Quickfire55 - sorry about the trouble.  I added the full HTML and Javascript above (edited post).  I hope this helps because I just can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: No it didn't work. I am going to have to rethink or try a different approach to get this to work.  Thanks so much for the help.  I really did appreciate it.

Comment: @RyanBennett, if you can post this on a web server somewhere and send me the link, I'd be willing to take a look at it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting it to display when you enter the field use the onFocus="method()" attribute. followed by onBlur="method()". this will display the block when you enter the field and hide it when you leave.

```
<input id="searchbox" type="text" onFocus="toggle_visibility('friendslist');" onBlur="toggle_visibility('friendslist')">

<ul id="friendslist" style="display: none;">
  <!--search results HTML-->
</ul>
```

teach a man to fish: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

// EDIT

I think Quickfire's answer is the best solution. but as I understand it you want you results to show/hide, so I modified his method to better suit your markup.

```
function toggle_visibility(id){

    //Get the total number of <li> within my search result
    var results=document.getElementById(searchResultID).childNodes.length;

    if (results > 0){ // we have more than 0 results
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        e.style.display = 'block'; // show the element
    }else{ //No search results, hide div

        e.style.display = 'none'; //hide the element
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry.  What does that mean? I am very new to javascript.  Can you explain that further?

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Are there any tricks that I missed?  Maybe there would be a better way to do it.