# How to display DIV on keyup in Input?

Tags: jquery, html, onkeyup

I have an global search `input` and when the user start typing it should display a hidden `div` with those results.

I cant get the div to display when keyup. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sksn7kgh/)

Thats my div:

```
 <div class=" container-fluid parent">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." id="GlobalSearchInput" style="padding:10px;">
  <div class="" id="showSearchDiv" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;height:450px;background-color:red;"></div>
  </div



    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#GlobalSearchInput").keyup(function() {
      function showGlobalSearch() {
        var x = document.getElementById('showSearchDiv');
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
          x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          x.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: you have a function defined within your keyup function `showGlobalSearch` which is never called...

Comment: Also even if the above is resolved you current code shows the div for first character, hides for second, shows for third, hides for fourth.. and so on... what is your expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your `keyup` event handler you define a `showGlobalSearch` which is never called.

Also defining a function is not useful here, unless you need the same code anywhere in your code.

So, here is the corrected code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#GlobalSearchInput").keyup(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('showSearchDiv');
    if($(this).val() == "") {
      x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" container-fluid parent">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." id="GlobalSearchInput" style="padding:10px;">
  <div class="" id="showSearchDiv" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;height:450px;background-color:red;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. But this div block is flickering, like on and  off. It should display unless the input box is empty.

Comment: @Cyber Updated answer.

Comment: That is the one. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Cyber it is not flickering now ?

Comment: @Cyber You're welcome. You can simplify some parts by calling `show` and  `hide` functions on the `div` with a "jQuery" (CSS) selector on the `div`'s `id`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sksn7kgh/1/)**

> I have an global search input and when the user start typing it should
>   display a hidden div with those results

So from what I can understand you need to display the div when ever user is typing something and hide it when nothing is typed. Try the below approach.

1. On every keyup you will check the input value length.
2. If its more than 0 then show the search result box else hide it.

---

Below is the sample code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#GlobalSearchInput").keyup(function() {
   if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
     $('#showSearchDiv').show();
   } else {
     $('#showSearchDiv').hide();
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- You have nested functions. Remove the line with `function showGlobalSearch() {` (plus the corresponding `}`.)
- You toggle the display for every keyup. You probably want to keep it visible after the first keyup, e.g. by checking the input length.

Also, I'd recommend to use jQuery as much as possible, and not mix it with other means to access the DOM (so no `getElementById`).

**The result:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#GlobalSearchInput").keyup(function() {
    var div = $('#showSearchDiv');
    if ($("#GlobalSearchInput").val().length > 0) {
      div.show();
    } else {
      div.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid parent">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." id="GlobalSearchInput" style="padding:10px;">
  <div class="" id="showSearchDiv" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;height:450px;background-color:red;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code and your code have some problem
1. need to use close tag 
and main this no need to use function for check this cause you already check onkey function

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#GlobalSearchInput").keyup(function() {
 var input_value = document.getElementById('showSearchDiv');
 // when value is not empty then div will show and 
 //when input value empty then div will hide
 if($(this).val() == "") {
   input_value.style.display = 'none';
 } else {
    input_value.style.display = 'block';
 }
});
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" container-fluid parent">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." id="GlobalSearchInput" style="padding:10px;">
    <div class="" id="showSearchDiv" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;height:450px;background-color:red;"></div>
</div>
```